# PayuMoney callback issue Opencart 1.5.6.4

Tags: php, payu

I am having some call back issues with PayuMoney payment gateway as after selecting PayuMoney as payment gateway, customers can successfully complete payment but after successful payment is being made customers cannot be redirected to my site. Instead a blank page comes with following URL: 
`http://www.example.com/index.php?route=payment/payu/callback/`

Though I get confirmation from PayuMoney that I have received order but at backend in my opencart admin account no new order is added. Additionally the item remains there in the checkout basket. I have searched through many posts and have found that a number of people are facing the same problem as mine but I couldn't get a satisfactory solution anywhere.

If I go into the mysql tables, the order is added but with an order status id of 0.

Comment: I am facing same issue too.

Answer (score 1):

even I was facing the same issue. Following changes worked for me,

Add the following line in 
**YOUR-SITE-DIRECTORY/catalog/controller/payment/payu.php**

```
$this->data['button_proceed'] = $this->language->get('button_proceed');
```

After this line,

> $this->data['button_confirm'] =
>   $this->language->get('button_confirm');

And change line numbers 27 and 28 to,

```
$this->data['productinfo'] = 'opencart products information';
//$this->data['productinfo'] = $this->model_payment_payu->getOptions($this->session->data['order_id']);
```

*Source: PayU support team*